# Restrictions on SQL order

Tags: mysql, select, restriction

Still new to asking questions here, so this is my second attempt at a problem I face.

I have a table that is already ordered by Score. Every record can be one of 3 types. I would like to reorder the table by Score but impose an additional restriction on the mix, in every 10 records. Particularly, there is a specific mix consisting of each of the 3 types.

In the example below, I want to have at least 2 of type C and at most 2 of type A

**What I have**

```
------------------------------------------
ID      Score      Type
------------------------------------------
1       100         A
2       99          B
3       97          B
4       92          A
5       91          C
6       85          A
7       83          B
8       81          B
9       75          B
10      70          B
11      65          A
12      61          C
13      59          B
```

**What I want**

```
------------------------------------------
ID      Score      Type
-----------------------------------------
1       100         A
2       99          B
3       97          B
4       92          A
5       91          C
7       83          B
8       81          B
9       75          B
10      70          B
12      61          C
```

I don't think this can be solved by Group By or usort in an efficient manner. My initial solution was to export to PHP and do the reordering there.

Comment: (1) tables aren't ordered. (2) What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server > 2005, I think you can use RANK to get at what you want. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want all rows with TYPE=C returned and all rows with TYPE=B returned, but only at most 2 rows with TYPE=A returned.

This will work in ORACLE - ROWNUM can be used in a subquery to limit the number of rows.

(In another database ROWNUM might not even be implemented)

```
SELECT 
T.*
FROM
(
    select *
    from
    (
            select T.ID, T.SCORE, T.TYPE 
            from YourTable T
            WHERE TYPE='A'
            ORDER BY T.SCORE DESC

    )
    WHERE ROWNUM <=2
    UNION 
    select *
    from
    (
            select T.ID, T.SCORE, T.TYPE 
            from YourTable T
            WHERE TYPE='B'
            ORDER BY T.SCORE DESC

    )

    UNION 
    select *
    from
    (
            select T.ID, T.SCORE, T.TYPE 
            from YourTable T
            WHERE TYPE='C'
            ORDER BY T.SCORE DESC

    )


) T
ORDER BY T.SCORE DESC;
```

Comment: Not quite. I would like this ordering to occur for every 10 rows. And I would also like to have a minimum of 2 Type C in every 10 rows.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by ordering "within every 10 rows"?

Comment: That means that the first 10 records would have at least 2 typeC, the second 10 records would have at least 2 typeC, and so on.

Comment: It depends - do you still want ordering to be by SCORE (descending)?  If you want the descending order on SCORE, that may take precedence over the at-least-2-C-per-10 and at-most-2-A-per-10 ordering requirements.   You can still use PHP to manually order the records (post processing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, score, a.type 
FROM (SELECT id, score, a.type, IF(@lasttype = (@lasttype:=a.type), @index:=@index+1, @index:=0) indx 
      FROM tablename t, (SELECT @lasttype:='', @index:=0) AS a 
      ORDER BY TYPE, score DESC) AS a 
WHERE (a.type NOT IN ('A', 'C') OR (a.type IN ('A', 'C') AND indx <= 2)) 
ORDER BY score DESC;
```